# expecting x but rendering y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following errors:

```
  1) Failure:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_invalid_information [/REDACTED/users_login_test.rb:32]:
expecting <"session/new"> but rendering with <["sessions/new", "layouts/application"]>


  2) Failure:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edit [/REDACTED/test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:11]:
expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>


  3) Failure:
UsersEditTest#test_successful_edit [/REDACTED/test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:22]:
expecting <"users/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Relevant code from user_login_test.rb:

```
test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'session/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'session/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end
```

users_edit_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = User.find_by_name(:testuser)
  end

    test "unsuccessful edit" do 
      log_in_as(@user)
      get edit_user_path(@user)
      assert_template 'users/edit'
      patch user_path(@user), user: { name: "",
                                      email: "foo@invalid",
                                      password: "foo",
                                      password_confirmation: "bar" }
     assert_template 'users/edit'
    end

    test "successful edit" do
      log_in_as(@user)
      get edit_user_path(@user)
      assert_template 'users/edit'
      name = "Foo Bar"
      email = "foo@bar.com"
      patch user_path(@user), user: { name: name,
                                     email: email,
                                     password: "",
                                     password_confirmation: "" }
     assert_not flash.empty?
     assert_redirected_to @user
     @user.reload
     assert_equal name, @user.name
     assert_equal email, @user.email
    end

end
```

After several grueling hours of trying to hunt down the problem, I am still unable to find it. Tracing through the several problems, I feel like it might be a problem with the following test login code:

```
  def log_in_as(user, options = {})
    password = options[:password] || 'password'
    remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
    if integration_test?
      get login_path
        post login_path, session: { email:      user.name,
                                   password:    password,
                                   remember_me: remember_me 
                                 } 
    else
        session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end
```

I'm happy to update with more information as needed, but I'm pretty much at a loss.

Comment: is that your controller? you are having test-sepcified code in your controller?  that looks wrong to me

Comment: Please show up your testing code to us...

Comment: The code is in my test helper

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply your answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems you redirected instead of rendering. Try that:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
```

to make sure you're redirected

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working through chapter 9 of the same [Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/), and I ran into pretty much the same issue. After playing around in the console for a while I decided to just test it manually in the browser and was indeed unable to get to my edit page even though I was logged in. Which got me thinking that it might not be a problem with my tests but instead with the authorization in the users_controller.

Turns out I had completely forgotten to put the redirect_to login_url (in the logged_in_user filter) within an unless block so it was always just redirecting to the login page no matter what. The correct code is:

```
def logged_in_user
  unless logged_in?
    flash[:danger] = 'Please log in.'
    redirect_to login_url
  end
end
```

Now my tests are passing. Perhaps you've run into a similar issue. Either way I've often found it useful to just return to the browser and try to replicate the integration tests manually, just to figure out if it's a problem with my code or I've just written a dodgy test.